# Chrome browser find call to APIs ? He

Tags: web-scraping

I am using Chrome for some web scraping. How can I find manually the call to API endpoints url ?
The way I do it now it going to `Network` and look link by link. Is there a better way to quickly identify the call to database endpoints ?

Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or similar network sniffers.

You start fiddler. Then as you navigate to your website of interest, fiddler is going to show you all the url's that are sent to the website, as well as the website's responses.